# Conversion of Family Tree Maker (v6) 1999 files to Ancestry-readable format

Tags: ancestry.com, software-recommendations, family-tree-maker, data-transfer

I have just re-subscribed to Ancestry.com.  I haven't done genealogy since before my daughter was born 21 years ago (pre Internet access).  I have 1999 (Family Tree Maker) FTM files version 6. Windows version. How do I get my trees information to upload or convert to Ancestry.  I tried a 3rd party app to convert couldn't get it to load.

Comment: Welcome to Geneaalogy & Family History, Cheryl. I'm removed your name from the post as our way of showing that is in your profile -- click on user10968 and go to the tab to Edit your profile. You can change your display name to (pretty well) whatever you like and also (if you wish) add some information about yourrself (wholly optional).

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! What is the file extension (the part of the filename after the dot) for your FTM files?

Comment: Possibly helpful related question: https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/10107/97